# Pact verification failed - Provider test .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pact, pact-net

Hi I am trying to write my Provider test. I am setting up Provider State Middleware and using the Startup.cs file as demonstrated in the sample code. I get this error when I run my provider test though. Any advice?
:

### Verifier Output

Verifying a pact between API Consumer and My API

A GET request to retrieve the weather
Given data
Request Failed - error sending request for url (http://localhost:7058/weather): operation timed out

Failures:

1. Verifying a pact between API Consumer and My API Given There is data - A GET request to retrieve the weather - error sending request for url (http://localhost:7058/weather): operation timed out

Here are the logs:

```
Verifier Logs
-------------
2023-07-31T10:46:02.441273Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier: Executing provider states
2023-07-31T10:46:02.441305Z  INFO ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier: Running setup provider state change handler 'There is data' for 'A GET request to retrieve the weather'
2023-07-31T10:46:02.445733Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather forecasts"}: pact_verifier::provider_client: Sending HTTP Request ( method: POST, path: /, query: None, headers: Some({"Content-Type": ["application/json"]}), body: Present(54 bytes, application/json) ) to state change handler
2023-07-31T10:46:02.446003Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather forecasts"}: reqwest::connect: starting new connection: http://localhost:7058/    
2023-07-31T10:46:02.454204Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: hyper::client::connect::http: connecting to [::1]:7058
2023-07-31T10:46:02.454764Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: hyper::client::connect::http: connected to [::1]:7058
2023-07-31T10:46:02.618901Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: hyper::client::pool: pooling idle connection for ("http", localhost:7058)
2023-07-31T10:46:02.618935Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier::provider_client: State change request: Response { url: Url { scheme: "http", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("localhost")), port: Some(7058), path: "/provider-states", query: None, fragment: None }, status: 200, headers: {"content-length": "0", "date": "Mon, 31 Jul 2023 10:46:02 GMT", "server": "Kestrel"} }
2023-07-31T10:46:02.619044Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier: State Change: "ProviderState { name: "There is data", params: {} }" -> Ok({})
2023-07-31T10:46:02.619059Z  INFO ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier: Running provider verification for 'A GET request to retrieve the weather'
2023-07-31T10:46:02.619118Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier: Verifying a HTTP interaction
2023-07-31T10:46:02.619144Z  INFO ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier::provider_client: Sending request to provider at http://localhost:7058/
2023-07-31T10:46:02.619146Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather forecasts"}: pact_verifier::provider_client: Provider details = ProviderInfo { name: "Weather API", protocol: "http", host: "localhost", port: Some(7058), path: "/", transports: [ProviderTransport { transport: "http", port: Some(7058), path: Some("/"), scheme: None }] }
2023-07-31T10:46:02.619156Z  INFO ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier::provider_client: Sending request HTTP Request ( method: GET, path: /weather, query: None, headers: None, body: Missing )
2023-07-31T10:46:02.619158Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: pact_verifier::provider_client: body:

2023-07-31T10:46:02.619179Z DEBUG ThreadId(01) verify_interaction{interaction="A GET request to retrieve the weather"}: hyper::client::pool: reuse idle connection for ("http", localhost:7058)
```

This is my test that I got from the sample code:

```
public class ProviderTests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly WebApplication server;
    public Uri ServerUri { get; }
    private readonly PactVerifier verifier;

    public ProviderTests(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        ServerUri = new Uri("http://localhost:7058");
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
        builder.WebHost.UseUrls(ServerUri.ToString());
        builder.AddBuilderServices(); //my own method which I use to normally add services to my app, // before it starts
        var startup = new TestStartup(builder.Configuration);
        startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
        server = builder.Build();
        startup.Configure(server, builder.Environment);

        server.Start();

        this.verifier = new PactVerifier(new PactVerifierConfig
        {
            LogLevel = PactLogLevel.Debug,
            Outputters = new List<IOutput>
                {
                    new XunitOutput(output)
                }
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        server.DisposeAsync();
        verifier.Dispose();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void EnsureSomethingApiHonoursPactWithConsumer()
    {

        string pactPath = my path

        try
        {
            this.verifier
                .ServiceProvider("My API", ServerUri)
                .WithFileSource(new FileInfo(pactPath))
                .WithProviderStateUrl(new Uri(ServerUri, "/provider-states"))
                .Verify();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        
    }
}
```